# How does Vue choose whether a select option will become selected when app starts?

Tags: vue.js

I have this app: https://jsfiddle.net/punter/ggatev5k/1/ , also posted here:

```
<div id="app">

<select v-model="teamsSelected">
    <option v-for="team in teams" :value="{id: team.id, name: team.name}">{{team.name}}</option>
</select>

</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        teams: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Bayern'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Manchester'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Barcelona'},
            {id: 4, name: 'PAOK'},
        ],
        teamsSelected: {id: 2, name: 'Manchester'},
    },
});
</script>
```

I was surprised to see that an option became selected, even though the === does not return true between this.teams[1] and this.teamsSelected.

Therefore Vue doesn't rely on === to see if it will select by default an option from `<select>`. It has some other way to decide. Which way is that? Is that way described anywhere on the web, in the official documentation or elsewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the code where Vue [decides if an `option` is selected](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L8003):

```js
function setSelected (el, binding, vm) {
  actuallySetSelected(el, binding, vm);
```

It actually [uses a `looseEqual()` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L8027-L8039) to compare:

```js
function actuallySetSelected (el, binding, vm) {
  // ...
  for (var i = 0, l = el.options.length; i < l; i++) {
    // ...
    if (isMultiple) {
      // ...
    } else {
      if (looseEqual(getValue(option), value)) {
        if (el.selectedIndex !== i) {
          el.selectedIndex = i;
        }
        return
      }
  // ...
}
```

Which, you can infer by the name, [does a loose equality check](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L280-L284):

```js
/**
 * Check if two values are loosely equal - that is,
 * if they are plain objects, do they have the same shape?
 */
function looseEqual (a, b) {
```

## The reason?

Using a looser equality comparison is just a design decision, naturally. But I could [track it](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blame/v2.5.16/src/platforms/web/runtime/directives/model.js) and the `looseEqual` usage was added to [**fix an issue (#3673)**](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3673).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used v-model directive
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model

The selected option will be the one that matches the model. If no option value matches the model, you won't have anything selected by default.